# How to get current class name in Netbeans code template?

Tags: netbeans, code-templates

I want to write code template for logger in Netbeans:

```
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(XXXXXX.class).warn("${cursor}");
```

I can't find syntax to insert current class name into template (see *XXXXXX* placeholder above) in [reference](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorUsersGuide#How_to_use_Code_Templates).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created the following code template:

```
private static final ${LOGGER_TYPE type="org.slf4j.Logger" default="Logger" editable=false} LOGGER = ${LOGGER_FACTORY type="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" default="LoggerFactory" editable=false}.getLogger(${CLASS editable="false" currClassName}.class);
```

and I have associated it to the abbreviation `log`.

So at the cursor:

```
...
public class MyClass {
    |
...
```

I type `log` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and NetBeans expands the text:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
...
```

I have also:

- `logd` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- `logw` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- `logi` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- `loge` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

coded as:

```
${LOGGER_CONST default="LOGGER" editable=false}.debug("${logMessage}");
${LOGGER_CONST default="LOGGER" editable=false}.warn("${logMessage}");
${LOGGER_CONST default="LOGGER" editable=false}.info("${logMessage}");
${LOGGER_CONST default="LOGGER" editable=false}.error("${logMessage}", ex);
```

that generate:

```
LOGGER.debug("logMessage");
LOGGER.warn("logMessage");
LOGGER.info("logMessage");
LOGGER.error("logMessage", ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current class name you need to use this in your code template: `${classVar editable=false currClassName default=getClass()}`